# Context switching failing in the mobile apps with chrome version 115.XX.XX.XX

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webview, appium, seleniummanager

Exception: CONTEXT SWITCHER: Exception while switching context: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '115.0.5790'.
E               Stacktrace:
E               UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '115.0.5790'.

I have chrome driver version 115.0.5790.170 in the env path.

I have upgraded my selenium version 4.11.2 and appium python client to 2.11.1

I have tried chrome driver version 114 and 115, both failed.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload` flag while starting appium, the issue with chromedriver is you require exact version and a version mismatch throws the error you are getting.

Comment: I have tried it but still facing the same issue. I am facing this issue after google released chrome for testing

Comment: is it possible for you to share the capabilities you are using, and mean time before switching context have you tried checking available context using getContext